# How does this max() expression in Python work?

Tags: python, lambda, max

Here's the code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = {}
b[1] = 10
b[2] = 8
b[3] = 7
b[4] = 5
print max(a,key=lambda w: b[w])
```

This prints out `1`.

I don't understand how `max(a,key=lambda w: b[w])` is being evaluated here though; I'm guessing for each value i in a, it finds the corresponding value b[i] by

1. saving the current value of i as w in the lambda function
2. getting the corresponding value from b[i] and storing it in key.

But then why does it print out 1 instead of 11? Or why doesn't it print out 10, since that's really the maximum number?

Comment: Almost afraid to ask, but why did you imagine it might produce 11? 1 + 10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`max(a,...)` is always going to return an element of `a`. So the result will be either 1,2,3, or 4.
For each value `w` in `a`, the key value is `b[w]`. The largest key value is 10, and that corresponds with `w` equalling 1. So `max(a,key=lambda w: b[w])` returns 1.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = {}
b[1] = 10
b[2] = 8
b[3] = 7
b[4] = 5
c = a + b.values()
print max(*c)
```

Comment: why is bad? you can also do the same without concatenate the values if a and b are huge.

Comment: because it's so far from what OP is trying to do, that it's just frustrating

Comment: why the max(*c)? Are you trying to dereference c?

Comment: @Goose Bumper: if `c` refers to `[1, 42, 666]` then `max(*c)` is equivalent to `max(1, 42, 666)` (see `http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls`). My downvote is because that is obscure and inefficient as well; `max(c)` gives the same result (see `http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max`).